# Why Bash script won't extend ~/.bashrc?

Tags: linux, bash

On my bash script, I try to extend my bashrc, with the following lines :

```
        to_print="alias $nom_machine='ssh $nom_machine'"
        target_file="~/.bashrc"
        echo -e "$to_print" >> "$target_file"
```

When executed, I got an error :

```
 ~/.bashrc: No such file or directory
```

But the file exists, it is 236 lines :

```
$ cat ~/.bashrc | wc -l
236
```

What is wrong on my script ?

I am on linux ubuntu 14.05

Comment: Invoke `foo="~/.bashrc"; set -x`. Then `cat ~/.bashrc > /dev/null` and `cat "$foo" > /dev/null` – and you will see the difference. To revert: `set +x; unset foo`.

Answer (score 1):

According to this source (https://askubuntu.com/questions/510216/trouble-using-cd-command-with-or-home-in-bash-scripting), you should use:

```
eval echo -e "$to_print" >> "$target_file"
```

The reason is given as

> The problem is the tilde expansion happens before variable expansion

Answer (score 0):

The ~ (tilde) doesn't always behave as you would expect it to when used in a script or within quotes (I wouldn't guarantee that `cat "~/.bashrc"` behaves the same), I would recommend preferring `${HOME}` (with or without braces) instead.